# Calculating next date in Turbo Pascal

Tags: turbo-pascal

```
program date;
uses wincrt;

var
m,ch,ch1,ch2,ch3: string ;
mois,j,a,b: integer ;

begin
write('a');read(a);
write('j');read(j);
write('mois');read(mois);
case mois of
1,3,5,7,8,10: if j<31 then
                          begin
                          b:=j+1;
                          m:=str(b,ch)+'/'+str(mois,ch2)+'/'+str(a,ch3);
                          else  if j=31then
                          b:=1;
                          s:=mois+1;
                          m:=concat(str(b,ch),'/',str(s,ch2),'/',str(a,ch3));
                          end
                          else m:='erreur';    
4,6,9,11:if j<30 then
                 begin
                 b:=j+1;
                 m:=concat(str(b,ch),'/',str(mois,ch2),'/',str(a,ch3));
                 end                         
                 else j=30 then
                 begin
                 b:=1;
                 s:=mois+1;
                 m:=concat(str(b,ch),'/',str(mois,ch2),'/',str(a,ch3));
                 end
                 else m:='erreur';
2:if j<28 then
      begin
      b:=j+1;
      m:=concat(str(b,ch),'/',str(mois,ch2),'/',str(a,ch3));
      end
      else if j=28 then
      begin
      b:=1;
      m:=concat(str(b,ch),'/',str(mois,ch2,'/',str(a,ch3));
      end
      else if((a mod 4=0)AND (a mod 100<>0)) or ((a mod 100=0)and(a mod 400=0)) then
               if j<29 then
               begin
               b:=j+1;
               m:=concat(str(b,ch),'/',str(mois,ch2,'/',str(a,ch3));
               end
               else if j=29 then
               begin
               b:=1;
               m:=concat(str(b,ch),'/',str(mois,ch2,'/',str(a,ch3));
               end
               else m:='erreur';
12:if j<31 then
     begin
     b:=j+1;
     m:=concat(str(b,ch),'/',str(mois,ch2,'/',str(a,ch3));
     end
     else if j=31 then
     begin
     b:=1;
     s:=a+1;
     m:=concat(str(b,ch),'/',str(mois,ch2,'/',str(s,ch3));
     end;       
writeln(m);
end.
```

this is my program i hope  you be able to help me

Comment: What's your program supposed to do?

Comment: You didn't describe what the problem is supposed todo, what is failing and if there are any errors. Without this information, we can't help.

Comment: "i have written a program in turbou pascal and it didnt work " -  worst title ever

Comment: damn you, turbo pascal, and your non-working ways!

Comment: My bet is that it's doing some calendar calculations.

Comment: the program is supposed to give you the day after any day you give     exemple 1/1/2010 give you 2/1/2010

Comment: I have written a program in Turbo Pascal and it *did* work

Comment: Ok, now edit your question to include that description, and also include what *does* happen when you run the program

Comment: when i run the program it writes  erreur 42 erreur in expression with   m:=str(b,ch)+'/'+str(mois,ch2)+'/'+str(a,ch3);

Answer (score 2):

It may be a good idea to indent the code according to the begin/end-blocks. This make it very easy to spot unpaired begin/end statements.

```
m:=str(b,ch)+'/'+str(mois,ch2)+'/'+str(a,ch3);
```

It is a long time since i did something with Turbo Pascal, but if i remember correctly, str is a procedure. So it does not return anything.

In order to simplify your program, it may be a good idea, to only calculate the new variables "b", "mois" and "a" inside the case block. And then do the transformation to a string once after the case-block.

```
str(b, ch);
str(mois, ch2);
str(a, ch3);
m := ch + '/' + ch2 + '/' + ch3;
```

Comment: it worked but i have a new problem

Comment: +1 for helping the needy